# "API is dedicated to mobile devices"

Tags: word-choice

I am writing introductory paragraph and I want to express that some API will be used by mobile devices. Originally I started with "dedicated to" because it is direct translation from my native Czech language but I feel that it is not appropriate. That **dedicate** is better suited in sentences like "I dedicate this Oscar to my mum". Is "API is dedicated to mobile devices" ok or not? If not, how to replace it?

Comment: *APIs dedicated to mobile devices* will mean those are exclusively for those mobile devices only. **And it's still weird.** What you want to convey? Merely using *...some APIs will be used by mobile devices.* is absolutely okay and clear. What's the problem?

Comment: I used following sentence in my document: "This API is used by XY application running in mobile devices." I wondered if the usage of "dedicated" is correct or not. Czech adjective would be "určen" and it can be best expressed as "created for, designed for" and so forth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although your phrase-

> API is dedicated to mobile devices

Is somewhat decent, we can rephrase it to be more exact-

> - API is exclusively used by mobile devices
> - API is exclusively *dedicated* to mobile devices

Comment: Can "dedicated" be used in this context?

Comment: @LeosLiterak Yes, it can.

Comment: The phrase "exclusively dedicated" is redundant, as *X['s use (that we're talking about usage is understood when discussing APIs)] is dedicated to Y* already means *X is exclusively used by Y*.